# Assign Unicode values to char

Tags: c++

My code includes a loop in which checks every character of a `std::string`, assign it to a char variable, which fails its assertion when `-1 >= c >= 255`.

It is a method from a JSON parser class that it's not mine:

```
static std::string UnescapeJSONString(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string s = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = str[i]; // << HERE FAILS WHEN 'É' CHARACTER
        if ((c == '\\') && (i + 1 < str.length()))
        {
            int skip_ahead = 1;
            unsigned int hex;
            std::string hex_str;

            switch (str[i+1])
            {
                case '"' :  s.push_back('\"'); break;
                case '\\':  s.push_back('\\'); break;
                case '/' :  s.push_back('/'); break;
                case 't' :  s.push_back('\t'); break;
                case 'n' :  s.push_back('\n'); break;
                case 'r' :  s.push_back('\r'); break;
                case 'b' :  s.push_back('\b'); break;
                case 'f' :  s.push_back('\f'); break;
                case 'u' :  skip_ahead = 5;
                    hex_str = str.substr(i + 4, 2);
                    hex = (unsigned int)std::strtoul(hex_str.c_str(), nullptr, 16);
                    s.push_back((char)hex);
                    break;

                default: break;
            }

            i += skip_ahead;
        }
        else
            s.push_back(c);
    }

    return Trim(s);
}
```

How can I assign a Unicode value to a char? In this case the value is `É`, and the code is not ready to receive such a characters.

This is included into a dll library, and is giving me this error:

[image]

Comment: You can't, that's why `wchar_t` was invented. And none of the Unicode code points will be negative, although they may display as such when copied to a signed integer type. The formal definition of the character is U+00c9.

Comment: char are in this range : –128 to 127 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)

Comment: @MarkRansom And what should I do to fix the code? Using `wchar_t` will be enough? And why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote so I can't answer that. And `wchar_t` will be a good start but it's likely to ripple all through your code.

Comment: @willll, `char` has either the range of `signed char` or `unsigned char`, depending on the implementation. `signed char` only must support a range of -127 through 127. It's not fair to assume Microsoft's implementation is the same across the board.

Comment: @MarkRansom I edited my code to show things that it uses. How can I `push_back` a `wchar_t`? Maybe there is a `wpush_back_t`?

Comment: @MarkRansom : Then I would use std::wstring

Comment: @chris : right, testing against CHAR_MIN/CHAR_MAX make more sense

Comment: It doesn't make sense to iterate through unicode string with a for loop, use library like [utf8-cpp](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/), a code point is represented by `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

The std::string doesn't use Unicode.  This is evident because there is a method c_str that lets you get a char array from the std::string.

Answering your question, your test is wrong:

```
-1 >= c && c >= 255
```

It should be:

```
-1 <= c && c <= 255
```

But you can't get c anywhere near 255 since the char is signed. 
If you want to get 255 out a char it needs to be

```
unsigned char
```

This will not let you reach -1 though.

Read about char*'s here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

see char arrays here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/

see std::string here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: `-1 <= c <= 255` is wrong. `-1 <= c` results in a `bool`, which is compared against 255.

Comment: you can store UTF-8 in std::string, and char can be signed or unsigned

Comment: You can see the error by yourself, I've just added it

Comment: @chris  Yes, sorry... I wasn't thinking when I posted that.

Comment: JSON is typically UTF-8 encoded.  Either decode the whole thing to `wchar_t` before parsing it, or parse it as UTF-8 and decode individual substrings to `wchar_t` when needed.

Comment: My test? No, is the assertion that fails. In other words, the condition `-1 >= c && c >= 255` gives `false`. The only thing my code does to fail is `char c = 'É'`